# The [stack] of different means of this tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at the tag [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack). **The stack** is a crucial part of a low-level language, as that is the region in memory where all automatic variables are allocated. Tagging questions about stack memory as [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) makes logical sense. However, the description of the tag seems to imply that the tag pertains to **stack-based languages**.

- What should [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) refer to?
- Should [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) be eliminated altogether and be split into [stack-memory](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-memory) and [stack-based-languages](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-based-languages)?
- How should we otherwise handle and disambiguate this tag?

Comment: Note that a stack is also a structure in many languages, and there's also a queue tag, it might be worthwhile to have a tag pertaining to the stack structure as well

Answer (score 3):

#### Make [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) mean the region in memory, and create two another tags (probably [stack-based-languages](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-based-languages) and [stack-structures](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-structures)) meaning stack-based languages and the stack structure respectively.

Answer (score 2):

## [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) alone is too ambiguous

I say we nuke [stack](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) and potentially blacklist it down the road if this becomes a problem. People are always going to misuse a tag that generic, no matter what we put in the tag wiki.

Then we can make new tags for things like

- [stack-based-languages](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-based-languages) for stack-based programming languages (we could make this even more unambiguous by having it be [concatenative-language](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concatenative-language) and then synonymizing [stack-based-languages](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-based-languages) to the former).
- [stack-data-structure](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-data-structure) for the stack, as a data structure.
- Something for the place where automatic variables are declared. Maybe [automatic-memory](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-memory) or [automatic-storage](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-storage), though it would be nice to fit the word "stack" in there somewhere as part of a longer name.

Comment: The third one should be named `call-stack`, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack