# The [queue] is too long

Tags: discussion, tags

The [queue](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/queue) tag's wiki description seems to refer to the queue structure:

> For questions about the implementation or design of queues within a programming language. A queue is a first-in-first-out collection.

...from the tag wiki. However, the question [Why are there no (practical) queue-based languages?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/why-are-there-no-practical-queue-based-languages) is tagged [queue](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/queue). Should there be seperate tags for questions pertaining to queue-based languages and questions about the design/implementation of the queue structure?

Answer (score 2):

#### No

I think, as evidenced by that question, queue based languages are rare so there is no need for a new tag.

You can argue that the queue tag does or does not apply to that question.
I would argue that it "is close enough" as the properties of a queue based language follow from the properties of a queue.

Note this is a different situation from the [stack tag](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/the-stack-of-different-means-of-this-tag) where all three meanings are distinct and useful for PLDI